AWS Amplify uses legacy expo CLI in CI builds
AWS Amplify uses the legacy expo CLI (with npm install --silent --global expo-cli and expo build:web in build settings) by default. This doesn't work with some of the features (and I imagine will probably get worse as the new "local" expo CLI becomes more worked into things) and throws a build error once I added Auth components (passed for the bare demo builds without Auth libs). So I want to replace the old expo build:web with the equivalent using the new expo CLI but I haven't found any obvious replacement. I've tried variants on start (e.g. npx expo start --web) but they've all failed because they're trying to build and run.
Should I be using eas-cli build? That seems wrong cause it's outsourcing the build. Is there some expo build ... command I'm missing in the new CLI? Also does anyone know where this same issue could be submitted to AWS so they might update their default build yaml?

Oops, tried one more thing after posting this and it worked. The magic line to include under build commands was: npx expo export -p web --output-dir web-build
N.B. --output-dir web-build is included because the artifact dir was pointing there and I didn't want to change it.
